# how to pass screen.height & screen.width in vue test case | Jest Framework

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have used screen.height & screen.width for js operations. I can't able to pass the test case. (code coverage). I am using vue utils - Jest framework.
below My js code

```
const clientWidth = this.clientWidth ? this.clientWidth : screen.width;
const clientHeight = this.clientHeight ? this.clientHeight : screen.height;
```

Below what i have tried in my test case

```
it('should set the height of window screen', () =>{
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'screen', {         
    height: {
        value: 100,
    }
    configurable: true, 
});
```

How to write test case for this scenario.

Comment: What code do you test? If it's window.screen then it makes more sense to mock it on window.

Comment: @EstusFlask its not window.screen

Comment: @EstusFlask its not global screen. I have update my js code. Please look into it

Comment: @EstusFlask Actually i am a new to js. i tried screen.height in console. It shown some value. while i try window.screen.height, it also return same value.

Comment: I see. It confused me that you tried to mock it on HTMLElement. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. It will work.

```
global.screen.width = 300;
global.screen.height = 540;
```

Comment: getting the following trying this: 

Cannot set property width of [object Screen] which has only a getter

Answer (score 2):

In this case `screen` is `window.screen`, which is an instance of `window.Screen`. In both browsers and Jest's simplified DOM implementation (jsdom) it consists of read-only properies that are implemented with property descriptors.

Either `screen` property can be mocked on `window` object with `Object.defineProperty`, or `width` and `height` can be mocked separately on either `Screen.prototype` or `screen` with `Object.defineProperty`.

Mocking a property with Jest spy allows for automatic clean-up after each test without restoring property descriptors in `afterEach`, also reduces the boilerplate caused by the use of `Object.defineProperty` manually:

```
jest.spyOn(screen, 'height', 'get').mockReturnValue(100);
expect(screen.height).toBe(100);
// evaluate piece of code that uses `screen`
```

Comment: Cannot spyOn the height property; it is not a function -> I am receiving error like this

Comment: From this error I suppose you're doing `jest.spyOn(screen, 'height')`. It should be `jest.spyOn(screen, 'height', 'get')` instead.

Comment: No I tried this one 
`const spy = jest.spyOn(screen, 'height', 'set'); screen.height = 150;  
 expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  expect(screen.height).toBe(150);`

Comment: Spying on `set` doesn't serve a good purpose and should result in error. screen.height is read-only.

Comment: in my test case i have to pass the screen height. so what will be the solution.

Comment: It should be exactly like the answer says, `jest.spyOn(screen, 'height', 'get').mockReturnValue(100)` before it's used in a component. The same applies to screen.width.

Comment: Yes you're right @Estus. It will be work.